# Using Multiple Database Tables with Custom Sql Statements cant İngest and Load Data to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, data-ingestion

I'm trying to ingest from some tables and load into bigquery using Multiple Database Tables pluggin and as data selection option I choose custom Sql Statement but can't ingest data to bigquery , getting error :  ": BigQuery Multi Table has no outputs. Please check that the sink calls addOutput at some point".

There may be some missing something so here my plugin config below ;

[plugin_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoc6d.png)

[pipline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxLns.png)

I try to not give Table Aliases but its wont work too.
thanks for any advice .

Comment: Try enabling the 'Allow flexible schemas in Output' property in your BigQuery Multi Table sink.

Answer (score 0):

Set a runtime argument as follows:
key = multisink.[table_name] - where table_name is value of table name column from a record in input dataset
value = is the schema of the target table.

Example -- >

```
multisink.Persons
---------------------------

{ 
    "name": "Persons", 
    "type": "record", 
    "fields": [
        {"name": "PersonID", "type": "int"}, 
        {"name": "LastName", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "FirstName", "type": "string"}, 
        {"name": "Address", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "City", "type": "string"} 
    ]
}

-----------------------------
multisink.Patient
-----------------------------
{ 
    "name": "Patient", 
    "type": "record", 
    "fields": [
        {"name": "Patient_ID", "type": "int" }, 
        {"name": "Patient_code", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "Patient_name", "type": "string"}
    ]
}
```